# Help in getting color on an ocean modifier plane with solidify

Tags: ocean-simulation

I've managed to find some tips on the forum on making an ocean by using a plance + ocean + solidify

But I can only color the upper surface while i want the "depth\volume" of the ocean to have color as well.

Anyone know how can I achieve this?

screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: You could use the same method and just use a math node to lower the value at the point it shifts colour.

Comment: To get the best effect, you should apply the modifiers first. However, I notice in your shading graph that you're only using the Z coordinate - when I tested, Z did not give depth, but X and Y did, but these axes on their own cause distortions. You will have to play with combinations of "CombineXYZ" axis values, along with some manipulation of the mapping node to make it look right.